# I am trying to write a shell script to replace the path with an empty string

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
path=/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages/main/media/file.txt
```

I wanted to replace `/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages` with empty string "".

So that I should get the output like `main/media/file.txt`
how can we achieve it with bash scripting?

Comment: See the [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section of the manual. Specifially `${path/old/new}` replacement operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
prefix="/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages/"
string="/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages/main/media/file.txt"
foo=${string#"$prefix"}
echo "${foo}"
```

Take a look at the documentation for the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats perfect! and thanks for the doc. 
But if we wanted to use it in a for loop, how it works.
For example: 

#!/usr/bin/env bash

prefix="/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages/"
for foo in $bar; do

Comment: To brief, I have sub folders in packages (packages/main/media), when I try to push to s3 bucket, only files are pushed but I want it pushed with the main/media/files* for this directory. How can we achieve it with the loop.
For example: 

#!/usr/bin/env bash
prefix="/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages/"
files=$(find "$prefix" -type f)
for foo in $files; do
     path=${$foo#"$prefix"}// getting error stating bad substituion
     aws s3 cp "$path" "s3://mybucket$path"
 done

Answer (score 0):

It worked. Thanks again for your solution for this which makes it worked.

I used

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
prefix="/user/macintosh/git/branch/packages/"
files=$(find "$prefix" -type f) 
for foo in $files; do 
  path=${foo#"$prefix"}
  aws s3 cp "$foo" "s3://mybucket$path" 
done
```